# post value by javascript instead of php

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['answer'])) {
    echo $_POST['AnswerText'];
}
?>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "nicEdit.js"></script>
<form method="post">
    <textarea name="AnswerText" id="AnswerText" style="width: 100%;">
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="answer"/>
    <button type="button" onclick="SubmitFormData();">Click</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SubmitFormData() {
        var AnswerText = $("#AnswerText").val();
        alert(AnswerText);
    }

    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function () {
        nicEditors.allTextAreas()
    });
</script>
```

while working with nicEdit the php is working fine but i am not able to get the value of AnswerText by script.

any idia thanks in advance

Comment: Does the nicEditors.allTextAreas change the structure of your dom? Or is it remain the same.

Comment: remain same, no change

Comment: try `onclick="SubmitFormData" ` instead of  `onclick="SubmitFormData();" `

Comment: Do you have jquery installed on your site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

`var AnswerText = $("#AnswerText").val();`

use:

`var AnswerText = nicEditors.findEditor('AnswerText').getContent();`

See: http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/521/Javascript%20API